# How do I properly validate user input?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to create 4 four variables (`first_name`, `generic_location`, `whole_number`, and `plural_noun` ) and with those, have the code automatically make a short story.  I'm very new so bear with me.

I want to

1. make some security measure that will require the responses to all the variables except "whole_number" be an actual word from the English dictionary.
2. route all True inputs to an if statement that will control whether the story story is output or not.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

- i know the .isalpha won't filter the input for an actual word. initally my intent was to settle for just letters but now i want to make sure the input is at least in the enlgish dictionary. So if someone can make a reccomended for how i can do that, thank you!

```
first_name = input("Enter a first name."); 
if first_name.isalpha():
    first_name = True; 
    print(first_name); 
else:
    first_name = False; 
    print("Please use only letters."); 
whole_number = input("Enter a whole number."); 
if whole_number.isdigit():
    whole_number = True; 
    print(whole_number); 
else:
    whole_number = False; 
    print("Please use only numbers."); 
plural_noun = input("Enter a plural noun."); 
if plural_noun.isalpha():
    plural_noun = True; 
    print(plural_noun); 
else:
    plural_noun = False; 
    print("Please use only letters."); 
generic_location = input("Enter a generic location."); 
if generic_location.isalpha(): 
    generic_location = True; 
    print(generic_location); 
else:
    generic_location = False; 
    print("Please use only letters."); 
print(end=''); 
if(first_name, whole_number, plural_noun, generic_location == True):
    print(first_name, "buys", whole_number, "different types of", plural_noun, "at", generic_location, "."); 
else: 
    print("Oops please double check your answers!");
```

What I expect:

I expect I'm wrong but I'm hoping not.

I think I routed the variables correctly to the if statement parenting the short story by marking all the variables as "True".

however idk if I should make "short_story" a variable as well or is that redundant since the command only prints the code once?

```
if(first_name, whole_number, plural_noun, generic_location == True):
    print(first_name, "buys", whole_number, "different types of", plural_noun, "at", generic_location, "."); 
else: 
    print("Oops please double check your answers!");
```

Comment: Assigning `first_name = True` replaces whatever they entered as their name...

Comment: As an aside, loose the semicolons at the end of lines. Python allows it, but its completely unnecesary.

Comment: Mandatory link: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting until the end of all inputs to see if the variables are correct, you can keep asking the same question until the user gets it correct. This way, you'll never get to the final print unless all variables are the proper format.

##### Static Approach

```py
while not (first_name := input("Enter a first name: ")).isalpha(): 
    print("Please use only letters.")
    
while not (quantity := input("Enter a quantity: ")).isdigit(): 
    print("Please use only numbers.")
    
while not (plural_noun := input("Enter a plural noun: ")).isalpha(): 
    print("Please use only letters.")
    
while not (location := input("Enter a location: ")).isalpha(): 
    print("Please use only letters.")
    
# format with an fstring
print(f'{first_name} buys {quantity} different types of {plural_noun} at {location}.')
```

##### Dynamic Approach

```py
# alias
alpha  = str.isalpha
digit  = str.isdigit
fmt    = 'numbers', 'letters'

def get_message(msg:str, inputs:tuple) -> str:
    if msg.count('{}') != len(inputs):
        raise ValueError('bracket count and input length differ')

    output = []
    
    # input loop
    for label, func in inputs:
        # keep asking the same question until we get the proper answer
        while not func(in_ := input(f'Enter a {label}: ')):
            print(f'Please use only {fmt[func==alpha]}.')
            
        # store answer
        output.append(in_)
    
    return msg.format(*output)


# CONSTANTS
#             label        | function
FIRST_NAME  = 'first name' , alpha
PLURAL_NOUN = 'plural noun', alpha
QUANTITY    = 'quantity'   , digit
LOCATION    = 'location'   , alpha

# message config
inputs = FIRST_NAME, QUANTITY, PLURAL_NOUN, LOCATION
msg    = '{} buys {} different types of {} at {}.'
    
inputs2 = FIRST_NAME, LOCATION
msg2    = '{} went to {}.'

# results
print(get_message(msg, inputs))
print(get_message(msg2, inputs2))
```

The dynamic approach may seem more involved, but it automatically allows you to create unlimited sentences. It also allows for a much greater level of control. What if you realized that `isalpha` is not allowing you to input words that end in `'s`, but you have reached a point where you need that. With the static approach you have to reconsider every line containing `isalpha`. With the dynamic approach you can just make this adjustment:

```py
import re

# alias - ex: Freddy's, doesn't, they've, he'll, students'
alpha  = re.compile(r'[a-z]+(\'([st]|ve|ll)?)?', re.I).fullmatch
```

##### bonus

With a little extra effort you can automate the entire process.

```py
import re

constants = re.compile(r'{(\w)}').finditer
alpha     = re.compile(r'[a-z]+(\'([st]|ve|ll)?)?', re.I).fullmatch 
digit     = str.isdigit
fmt       = 'numbers', 'letters'

###           label        | function
FIRST_NAME  = 'first name' , alpha
NOUN        = 'noun'       , alpha
PLURAL_NOUN = 'plural noun', alpha
QUANTITY    = 'quantity'   , digit
LOCATION    = 'location'   , alpha


def get_message(msg:str) -> str:
    inputs = []
    for c in constants(msg):
        # get constant name
        rep = c.group(1) 
        # store constant value
        inputs.append(globals()[rep])
        # remove constant name from message, leaving only brackets
        msg = msg.replace(rep, '')
        
    output = []
    
    # input loop
    for label, func in inputs:
        # keep asking the same question until we get the proper answer
        while not func(in_ := input(f'Enter a {label}: ')):
            print(f'Please use only {fmt[func==alpha]}.')
            
        # store answer
        output.append(in_)
    
    return msg.format(*output)


messages = (
    '{FIRST_NAME} buys {QUANTITY} different types of {PLURAL_NOUN} at {LOCATION}.',
    '{FIRST_NAME} loves their {NOUN}.'
)

for message in messages:
    print(get_message(message))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! youve introduced a bunch to me i havent seen before like import, while not, and the f  inside of "while not func(in_ := input(f'Enter a {label}: ')):" which im not sure is the purpose. But ill looking into all this, again thanks a lot!